# Firestore .get() function NOT running in JQuery .on click function

Tags: jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Desired outcome:**

1. Click on a bootstrap card with #city-card, data-id=${cityName} and href="new.html".
2. Store the data-id value in a variable.
3. Get the cityName document from a collection in Firestore to use once on the new.html page

**What's happening:**

A. Firestore document will log to the console when preventDefault() IS present, but it prevents the page from going to the new href.

B. Firestore document will not log to the console when preventDefault() is NOT present and the pages loads to the new href.

I want the Firestore document to log to the console as the page loads to the new href.

**GIF Examples:**

A. [Working Correctly (with preventDefault();)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmDhV.gif)

B. [Works Incorrectly (withOUT preventDefault();)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJSRU.gif)

**Question:** How can I get the `docRef.get().then(function(doc){ });` to run without preventDefault in the .on click function so I can use that info on the new.html page?

**Sample Code:**

HTML CARD

```
<a id="city-card" data-id="${cityName}" href="location-page.html">
 <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
    <h4 class="card-title">San Francisco</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

JQUERY

```
var cityName = "san-francisco";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','#city-card',function(e){
      // e.preventDefault();
      //Stores data-id=${cityName} in variable cityPage
      const cityPage = $(this).data('id');
      console.log(cityPage);

      const docRef = db.collection("city").doc(cityPage)
      docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        var cityData = doc.data();
        var cityName = doc.id;
        console.log("cityName: " + cityName);
        console.log(cityData);
      });
  });
});
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out this morning with the help of a friend.

Fix was to populate a global variable on click, store that global variable in the query perameters and then access the global variable once the new page reloads.

Here's the code!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','#city-card',function(e){
    //Stores data-id=${cityName} in variable cityPage
    window.cityPage = $(this).data('id');
    var newCityPage = window.cityPage;
    //Returns redirectPage function
    return redirectPage(newCityPage)
  });
});
//Opens new window with newCityPage in the query perams
function redirectPage(newCityPage) {
    window.location = "file:///Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Surf-Trip/location- 
   page.html?newCityPage="+newCityPage;
    window.cityPage = newCityPage;
    return false;
}
//Gets query perams by name
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
//Storing the query perams in a constant
const newCityPage = getParameterByName('newCityPage');
//Pings Firestore for relevant newCityPage document
const docRef = db.collection("city").doc(newCityPage);
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
```